# I go to bathroom then I come to bed - is it correct?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple, future-time, future-constructions

Let's say I come home from work and I tell to my daughter:

> 1. I go to bathroom then I come to bed

Is it correct?

What about:

> 2. I go to bathroom then I'll come to bed
> 3. I'm going to bathroom then I'll come to bed

Are they wrong?

Comment: They nuance different meanings and effects, so which one is "correct" is whichever one nuances the meaning and effect you wish to convey.

Comment: I go to the bathroom everyday at least five times a day. Please realize that in English, the simple present is ONLY for a habitual thing, a general thing. Maybe you mean your wife. To your daughter: I'm going to the bathroom and then I'll **go** to bed. We never ever use the simple present unless we mean something in general: I work everyday to make my living. [with action verbs, anyway].

Comment: @Lambie thanks I've really appreciated your explanation. I'm glad I've asked this question, at least it means that something wasn't adding up in my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Lambie's comment, yes, "I go to bathroom then I come to bed" is wrong in the case you're describing.

If you're telling your daughter what you're about to do, "I go to the bathroom then I come to bed" isn't right, because it's present tense - it sounds as if you're already doing both of those things now, but you're not.  Since you're describing something you haven't done yet, you need some type of future tense.

> I'm going to the bathroom then I'll come to bed

is correct.  "Going to" indicates you haven't done something yet but you're on your way to do it now.  "I'll come to bed", you haven't even started to do that yet but you will.

(Notice, by the way, that it should be "to the bathroom", with a "the", but "to bed", with no "the".  I don't think there's any reason for this except traditional  idiom.)

---

Just for interest: there's only one time that two successive actions could both be present tense at once like that.  If you were describing your daily routine to someone, you could say:

> Every night, I go to the bathroom then I come to bed.

In that case, you're talking about several occasions at once, past, present, and expected future, which means that no tense really makes sense.  And the grammatically accepted thing in that case seems to be to use the present tense for everything.

Comment: And 'come to bed' implies that you will be joining your daughter in her bed!

Comment: @KateBunting we still sleep (me and her mother) with our daughter, she is only 2 years old.